# how to serve static files on google app engine

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

Basically I'm new to the google app engine, I have a folder called templates in which I have several files :

```
index.php
result.php
request.php
```

However on the yaml.app I figured out only how to run the server locally by making the templates/index.php default page.
I mean when I go to `http://localhost:8080` it is what I see. But when I do `http://localhost:8080/templates/index.php` it says 404 not found.
How Can I use all the files I want in any directory inside my app, is it somekind of rule I should add to my app.yaml?

Here is the current app.yaml im using :

```
application: sympy-live-hrd
version: 38

runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

libraries:
- name: numpy
  version: latest
- name: matplotlib
  version: latest

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  expiration: 1d

# cache-busting scheme
# request /static-(app version)/filename
- url: /static-[0-9]+/(.*)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*)

# if you're adding the shell to your own app, change this regex url to the URL
# endpoint where you want the shell to run, e.g. /shell . You'll also probably
# want to add login: admin to restrict to admins only.
- url: .*
  script: shell.application
```

The Shell.application is a python script that I edited to use templates/index.php as default

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles

Comment: I already red that documentation, but I'm still confused on how to achieve it.

Comment: Confused with **what** exactly?

Comment: On how the url handling works, I added my current app.yaml to the question.

Comment: If the files are inside *templates* directory then `static_dir` should be `static_dir: templates`.

Comment: Why are you tagging this as python?  It's a php question right?

Comment: @dragonx actually Im using both python and php in the same application.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I tried what you recommended, however now when I specify the url instead of being shown in the browser, the browser downloads the requested file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming index.php is a script?

I believe you have to run php scripts using the php runtime.  They won't run as scripts from the python runtime, so firstly, you won't be able to run the php scripts.

Second, you need a handler that will point to your templates folder, but that doesn't exist.

```
handlers:
- url: /templates
  static_dir: templates
  expiration: 1d
```

Note that this will just load the file, it won't run php files unless you're using the php runtime.

Comment: Yep I fixed the handlers part and as you said the php files don't get loaded but downloaded. can't I run python and php at the same time?

Comment: seems no, you should mention the runtime you want to use

Comment: Check out the new modules feature.  Different modules within an application can run different runtimes, but any single instance can only run one runtime.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/

What you're trying to do should be possible, but you would need to set up your php code in a php runtime module that handles the php urls.

Comment: Thanks! that's actually the solution that will get me things working.